# undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'

Tags: c++, opencv, ros, catkin

I'm trying launch cv_camera with ros but I couldn't compile this package in ros, I launched this command:

```
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps rossumo cv_camera
...
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/docker/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcv_camera.so: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/home/docker/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcv_camera.so: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/home/docker/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcv_camera.so: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(cv::String const&)'
/home/docker/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcv_camera.so: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/docker/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcv_camera.so: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::_OutputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** 
...
```

What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you linked opencv libraries?

Comment: This is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and the root cause was the conflicts between OpenCV 2 and OpenCV 3. We have to be very careful to set the LDFLAGS when the system has both OpenCV 2 and OpenCV 3 installed.